# c# datagridview multi-page print

Tags: c#, .net, printing, datagridview, datagrid

Could someone help and point out what might be wrong with this section of code?

I have an issue with a particular tutorial extract of code which outputs a printpreview from a datagridview in C#. I found the while iterration didn't work so I swaped it over with a for loop. But there is an issue with the mutliple page code. It generates what seems to be unlimited number of pages of the same overflowing first page, rather then segmenting the print into multiple pages using the e.HasMorePages parameter. Does the parameter need to be set as false at some point?

I followed the example in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlphP7cYE98

There appears to be a code extract which is similar to that of the videos on this site:

http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread1065047.html

```
        height = 100;
         while (i > dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (height > e.MarginBounds.Height)
            {
                height = 100;
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                return;
            }

            height += dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height;
         //....

         i++
```

Comment: As well as this site which contains a similar snippet of code http://www.w3-farsi.com/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%AA-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B2-datagridview/

Comment: I think there appears to be a similar solution posted as questions, which manages to have multiple pages from a datagridview, the solutions code can be found here (named: "DataGridViewTestApplication.rar ") http://arabteam2000-forum.com/index.php/topic/281581-%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B9-%D9%84%D8%B7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%A7-%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%88-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87/

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/316227-some-problems-understanding-how-to-use-ehasmorepages-and-setting-zoom/

Answer (score 1):

multiple pages doesn't work.
You never set

> e.HasMorePages = false

for the last pages, it will just create continuous pages and won't stop!